# What is the correct post request body for AWS Codepipeline webhook?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I have a codepipeline webhook defined below:

```
webhooks:
- arn: arn:aws:codepipeline:eu-west-1:$$$:webhook:codepipeline-webhook-test-staging
  definition:
    authentication: UNAUTHENTICATED
    authenticationConfiguration: {}
    filters:
    - jsonPath: $.ref
      matchEquals: refs/heads/{Branch}
    name: codepipeline-webhook-test-staging
    targetAction: Source
    targetPipeline: test-staging-pipeline
  tags: []
  url: https://eu-west-1.webhooks.aws/
```

I want the pipeline to fire whenever there is a post request to that url. I've tried posting with no body which returns http 200 but the pipeline hasn't triggered and I've tried different permutations of the following:

```
{
    "ref": "staging"
}
or
{
    "ref": "refs/heads/staging"
}
```

What is the correct json body to trigger the pipeline?

Comment: Try setting the filter to `matchEquals: refs/heads/staging`.

Answer (score 0):

@gshpychka's answer worked for me:

> Set the filter to matchEquals: refs/heads/staging

Thanks!